# Duplicate account

Tags: discussion

Looks like a new user has ended up with duplicate accounts, is it possible to get them merged?

[user1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/48541/hajie)
[user2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/48491/hajie)